# how to make javascript class derived from jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I want to make a constructor whose instances are jquery objects, so that

```
var obj = new MyConstructor();
$("body").append(obj); // append instance to html body
```

how do implement such a constructor ?

Comment: What does `MyConstructor` do?

Comment: Should it return an element or a string?

Comment: @Jason: I think the OP is asking that same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery object is just a DOM element which has been augmented (by jQuery). What is insufficient about this? Unless you have some other use case in mind, you don't need to do anything fancy with a constructor.

```
var $obj = $('<div>Foo bar baz</div>');
$('body').append($obj);

// really, all you need is this:
$('body').append('<div>Foo bar baz</div>');
```

Comment: Gah, thanks for the edit... I should not be writing code this tired.